# How to write a `sed` script that replaces the text enclosed between two markers with the contents of another file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a `sed` script that replaces the text enclosed between two markers with the contents of another file.

Say I have the following file with the markers `<!-- Start -->` and `<!-- End -->`:

```
# index.html
...
<!-- Start -->
<p>Old content</p>
<!-- End -->
...
```

And I want to replace the enclosed text with the content of this file:

```
# snippet.html
<p>New content</p>
```

I tried this `sed` script:

```
$ cat snippet.html | sed -i -e '/<\!-- Start -->/,/<\!-- End -->/ { r /dev/stdin' -e';d};' index.html
```

It replaces both the content and the markers, but I need to **keep the `<!-- Start -->` and `<!-- End -->` markers** so I can replace the content again in the future.

What changes should I make to the `sed` script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a temporal solution, I'm including the markers inside the `snippet.html`:

`<!-- Start --><p>New content</p><!-- End -->`

Comment: Don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed, [edit] your question so it contains all relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that you need to do to your code is add `//!` before the `d`:

```
cat snippet | sed -e '/<\!-- Start -->/,/<\!-- End -->/ { r /dev/stdin' -e '; //!d }' file
```

`//` is shorthand for "last match" ... so in the case of `/START/,/END/{ }` without any other match within `{ }`, it will match *both* `/START/` and `/END/`.

`//!d` ensures that the range, excepting the matching lines at the start and end, will be deleted.

ETA: as @potong raised in the comments, the use of `r /dev/stdin` seems to be a special case-- only the first `r` will add anything to the output stream.

Comment: I think this may insert the snippet file for each line between the markers.

Comment: @potong - I thought that, too, but it might be that in the special case of catting to stdin, the first `r` empties the pipe, and thereafter there's noting more to `r`?  Surprisingly, it works.

Comment: Indeed, `r snippetFile` behaves differently to `r /dev/stdin` with former appending the lines from `snippetFile` for each line in the input file whilst the latter `/dev/stdin` appends lines only once.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/<!-- Start -->/{n;r snippetFile' -e ':a;N;/<!-- End -->/D;s/\n//;ba}' file
```

Print the start marker and then append the snippet file.

Gather up lines until an end marker, removing their newlines and delete them using the `D` command, leaving the end marker as is.

N.B. The solution is in two parts as the `r` command demands a newline as a terminator (a separate command set has the same effect as a newline).

The above solution does not cater for empty markers for which a dummy line must be inserted:

```
 sed -e '/<!-- Start -->/{n;r snippetFile ' -e 's/^/\n/;:a;N;/<!-- End -->/D;s/\n//g;ba}' file
```

An alternative solution is to insert and append the markers to the snippet file:

```
sed -z 's/^/<!-- Start -->\n/;s/.*/&\\/mg;s/$/<!-- End -->/' snippetFile |
sed '/<!-- Start -->/,/<!-- End -->/c'"$(cat)" file
```

N.B. In this solution, the `c` command expects all its line but the last, to be terminated by `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the markers are alone on their lines:

```
cat snippet.html | sed -i -n -e '
    /<\!-- Start -->/r /dev/stdin
    1,//{;p;d;}
    /<\!-- End -->/,$p
' index.html
```

- `//` repeats the previous regex search

---

The code above fails if first marker is on first line of file. In that case, with GNU sed `0,//` can be used instead of `1,//`. Alternatively, this version should work correctly:

```
cat snippet.html | sed -i -n -e '
    /<\!-- $Start -->/{
        p
        r /dev/stdin
        :d
        n
        /<\!-- End -->/!bd
    }
    p
' index.html
```