# Is anything inside the string changed after binding operations?

Tags: regex, perl

```perl
my $s = 'x';
print("\$s is $s,\$s =~ s///r is ",$s =~ s///r, ".\n");
$s =~ /x/;
print("\$s is $s,\$s =~ s///r is ",$s =~ s///r, ".\n");
```

prints

```
$s is x,$s =~ s///r is x.
$s is x,$s =~ s///r is .
```

So what is changed after the third line?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about the behavior with an empty-string pattern.  Let's change the test a bit

```
perl -wE'$s = "x arest"; $s =~ /x a/; $r = ($s =~ s///r); say $s; say $r'
```

Prints the same `$s`, and then `rest`

It is the particular behavior when the pattern is an empty string that affects this, [per perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s%2FPATTERN%2FREPLACEMENT%2Fmsixpodualngcer)

> If the pattern evaluates to the empty string, the last successfully executed regular expression is used instead.

Apparently the `//` (empty string) pattern is literally replaced by the last match, and *that* is removed from the string here; then under `/r` the rest returned

```
perl -wE'$s = "x arest"; $s =~ /x a/; $r = ($s =~ s//X/r); say $r'
```

Prints `Xrest`.

A few notes

- This is not affected by `pos`, as this code works the same way

  ```
  perl -wE'$s = "x arest"; $s =~ /x a/g; pos $s = 1; $r = ($s =~ s///r); say $r'
  ```

  I've added `/g` so to be able to use `pos`.  Just uses `$&`?
- The section on [Repeated matches with zeo-length substring](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Repeated-Patterns-Matching-a-Zero-length-Substring) is clearly interesting in this regard, perhaps to explain the rationale for the behavior

Comment: If you add some replacement strings, they do insert into the string where `x` should match, so it seems to be true. E.g. `$s = 'xx'; $s =~ /x/; $s =~ s//e/r;` will now print `ex`. Perl magic, or bug. The documentation seems to say "magic", but what possible application could this have?

Comment: @TLP I think you can use it in the loop condition, while the last pattern may vary during the loop.

Comment: @zdim We'd have to get some of the old dragons in here to talk about ye olden days of Perl to know for sure.

Comment: @TLP -- `sed` also uses `//` as last match in both match and replacement, see for instance [this answer using `//!d`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850429/how-to-write-a-sed-script-that-replaces-the-text-enclosed-between-two-markers/72858701#72858701)

Comment: It doesn't look like a special case to me. `s///r` uses the last match, so is treated exactly like `s/x a//r`, which does a normal substitution - then due to the /r, returns the result of that substitution. I'm not seeing anything magic.

Comment: @stevesliva Yes, like the quote from docs above in the answer.  I've come to think that that is all there is to it -- with `//` it literally uses the last match (`$&`) -- and replaces it!  I've edited the answer accordingly.  Thanks for the comment and link

Comment: @DaveMitchell That's what I meant by "special case" -- instead of just matching an empty string which it actually has there (like an anchor at every character) it uses a previous match.  (The reason being to cut off infinite loops here or there, or perhaps just for convenience?)  Perhaps the wording with "special case" isn't good...?  (I elaborated right as your comment came -- thank you)

Comment: @zdim -- `//` is for match side, `&` for replacement.  Does work in match in perl too: `seq 0 9 | perl -ne ' if (/2/../6/) { print unless // }'` --> prints 3 4 5.   I had searched perlvar for something like `//` but did not think to simply try it.

Comment: @DaveMitchell Removed the "special case" wording.  (The behavior is a little particular though, I think)   Thank you

Comment: @TuffContender  Updated, to clean up and perhaps make clearer

Comment: @zdim -- explored this some more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316735/sed-replace-between-patterns-with-part-of-pattern/77318764#77318764).   Some nuances are unlike sed.