# sed: replace between patterns with part of pattern

Tags: sed

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I file that contains a multitude of snippets with the following pattern

```
Lemma <LEMMANAME> :
<LEMMASTATEMENT>
Proof.
<PROOF>
Qed.
```

which I am trying to replace by the following:

```
Lemma <LEMMANAME> :
<LEMMASTATEMENT>
Proof.
exact <LEMMANAME>
Qed.
```

- `<LEMMANAME>` does not contain any spaces. It can be any valid Coq identifier, so that includes unicode (however, I don't think any unicode currently occurs). The colon is terminated by a newline immediately (no spaces)
- `<LEMMASTATEMENT>` can be any number of lines, and can contain pretty much anything except for a newline starting with `Proof.`
- `Proof.` is terminated by a newline immediately (no spaces)
- `<PROOF>` can be any number of lines, and can contain pretty much anything except for a newline starting with `Qed.`
- `Qed.` is terminated by a newline immediately (no spaces)

I struggle matching on `<LEMMANAME>`, saving it to some variable (?), and then reusing it later. What I have so far is a script that replaces the proof with the constant string `LEMMANAMEHERE`: the following sed script correctly matches the `Proof.\n<PROOF>\nQed.` pattern, and replaces it with `Proof.\nexact LEMMANAMEHERE\nQed.`

```
sed -i '/Proof./,/Qed./c\Proof.\nexact LEMMANAMEHERE\nQed.' file
```

For example, when run on the first snippet, we obtain

```
Lemma <LEMMANAME> :
<LEMMASTATEMENT>
Proof.
exact LEMMANAMEHERE
Qed.
```

How do I extend this script such that I can insert `<LEMMANAME>` instead of the constant `LEMMANAMEHERE`? Preferably this uses `sed`, but a solution in something like `awk` works as well (the idea is to replace inline, not to create an augmented copy)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable, truly representative sample input and expected output. For example if `<PROOF>`  can actually be a multi-line string then show such a multi-line string. If your real input has multiple blocks to be replaced (and presumably other text not to be replaced) then show input that looks like that, not just 1 block. We need you to provide something that demonstrates your requirements and we  can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Regarding "the idea is to replace inline, not to create an augmented copy" - there is no editing inplace with Unix text-processing tools, unless you use `ed` to read the whole input into a buffer first then write it all out at the end (which awk, perl, etc. can also do). `sed -i`, `perl -i`, `ruby -i`, `gawk -i inplace`, whatever ... - they all use a temp file in the background and that `-i` is just syntactic sugar so you don't have to manually add the trivial `> tmp && mv tmp file` to the end of the command line for any tool that doesn't have so-called "inline" editing.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -i~ -lne '
    next if $p && ! /^Qed\.$/;
    $p = 0;
    print;
    $l = $1 if /^Lemma (.+) :$/;
    if (/^Proof\./) {
        print "exact $l";
        $p = 1;
    }
' -- file
```

- `-i~` makes the changes "in place", leaving a backup file with the `~` extension;
- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`;
- we use two variables, `$l` stores the lemmaname and `$p` is true when we are inside the proof. Therefore, we call [next](https://perldoc.pl/next) to skip printing the line until we find the `Qed.`;
- when the `Proof.` line is encountered, we print the stored lemmaname and set `$p` to 1 to skip printing the following lines up to the `Qed.`.

Comment: This only replaces the first line of `<PROOF>`, in other words, `Lemma x :\nTrue\nProof.\nbla1\nbla2\bla3\nQed.` turns into `Lemma x :\nTrue\nProof.\exact x\nbla2\bla3\nQed.`

Comment: @R.Bosman: You're right, my mistake. Should be fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @choroba if you're interested, I followed through that `unless //` investigation to its bitter end and it's attached to my sed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
    $0 == "Qed."   { inProof=0 }
    !inProof       { print }
    /^Lemma /      { lem=$2; sub(/:$/,"",lem) }
    $0 == "Proof." { print lem; inProof=1 }
' file
Lemma <LEMMANAME> :
<LEMMASTATEMENT>
Proof.
<LEMMANAME>
Qed.
```

If you want to modify the input file, change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` if you're using GNU awk or change `file` to `file > tmp && mv tmp file` otherwise.

Comment: When I understand the question right, you are missing the word `exact` in `exact <LEMMANAME>`  (between `Proof.` and `Qed.`).

Comment: @WalterA My understanding of the question is that `exact <LEMMANAME>` is not actually the string the OP wants printed - they're just trying to tell us they want the exact lemma name copied from the first line as opposed to some placeholder string. If I'm wrong they can always change `print lem` to `print "exact", lem`.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the question which parts of the example are literal vs which parts are descriptive placeholders. For example I initially thought `<PROOF>` was literal but that turns out to be a placeholder for multi-line freeform text.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^Lemma/h; /Proof\./,/Qed\./{//!d; /^Qed\./{x;s/Lemma/exact/;s/ ://p;x}}' file
```

- `/^Lemma/h` to hold the line with Lemma
- `/Proof\./,/Qed\./{}` in the range from Proof to Qed:

  - `//d!` delete the line if it's not Proof or Qed
  - `/^Qed\./{` for Qed lines:

    - `x` swap Qed into hold space, get Lemma line
    - `s/Lemma/exact/;s/ ://p` format exact around `<LEMMANAME>` and print
    - `x` get Qed line back

Note this is GNU sed but it should work with other forms of sed with semicolons before `}`.

> A note on converting `/START/,/END/ { //!d }` pattern to perl:
>
> Typically sed patterns expand easily to perl, like sed's `,` range
> operator is supported in perl as `...`.   However the nuances of `//`
> in perl make me think it's effectively `/$&/` which means it doesn't
> work quite the same as `//` in sed.  So you end up with this, which
> isn't as elegant:
>
> ```
> perl -pe '$l = $1 if /^Lemma (\S+)/;' \
>       -e 'if(/^Proof/.../^Qed/) {' \
>         -e '$_="" and next unless $& && //;' \
>         -e 'print "exact $l\n" if /Qed/ }' \
>       file
> ```
>
> There are 3 things that verbosify the perl:
>
> 1. `unless //` becomes `unless $& && //` because the first failed match of `//` resets `$&` to empty.
> 2. `d` in sed becomes `$_="" and next`.   The `next` alone doesn't work with `perl -p` because the `print` is in the `continue` block which `next` does not skip.
> 3. `perl -lp` doesn't work because it adds `\n` in the `continue` block.  So this code must add `\n` to explicit print.

Comment: Hmm. `$&&&//` might have to be a new [secret perl operator](https://catonmat.net/secret-perl-operators).  Bulldozer.

Comment: I'm investigating the // behaviour in Perl, [too](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11155031) :-)

Comment: @choroba [me, zdim... about 1yr ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720178/is-anything-inside-the-string-changed-after-binding-operations/73720432)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^Lemma <.*> :$/h;/^Proof\.$/{n;g;s/.*(<.*>).*/exact \1/}' file
```

Make a copy of the LEMMANAME and using pattern matching append it to the Proof. and manipulate as required.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sed`, I would do something like

```
sed -riz 's/Qed./\r/g;s/(Lemma )([^ \r]*)( :\n[^\r]*\nProof.\n)[^\r]*\r/\1\2\3Exact \2\nQed./g' file
```

However, the code is hard to read, please use another solution, like `awk` or a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
status="new"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  # First check in which block you are
  reg='Lemma ([^ ]*) :'
  if [[ $line =~ $reg ]];   then
    lemma="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    status="in_lemma"
  fi
  if [[ $line == "Proof." ]]; then
    status="start_proof"
  fi
  if [[ $line == "Qed." ]]; then
    status="Qed"
  fi
  # Next print line or change status when needed
  case "${status}" in
  "new"|"in_lemma" )
     echo "$line"
   ;;
  "start_proof")
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "Proof." "Exact ${lemma}"
    status="do nothing"
  ;;
  "Qed")
    echo "$line"
    status="new"
  ;;
  *)
    : # Do nothing
  ;;
  esac

done < file > file.new && mv file.new file
```

Answer (score -1):

With awk you load all data in a array "data", END this, and next read data, and if condition is true print next four lines,";" next,print Lamme file register and it index in a other file with command ">" after print.
All in one line awk command:

```
 awk '{data[NR]=$0}END{for(j in data)if((data[j] ~ /^Lemma /)&&(i=j)&&(data[i+2] !~ /^Proof\./)&&(data[i+4]) !~ /^Qed\./)print data[i]"\n"data[i+1]"\n"data[i+2]"\nexact "substr(data[i],7,index(data[i],"\:")-8)"\n"data[i+4];print i";"data[i] > ("Lamme_register.txt")}' file
```

if modifie same file use awk -i inplace:

```
awk -i inplace '{data[NR]=$0}END{for(j in data)if((data[j] ~ /^Lemma /)&&(i=j)&&(data[i+2] !~ /^Proof\./)&&(data[i+4]) !~ /^Qed\./)print data[i]"\n"data[i+1]"\n"data[i+2]"\nexact "substr(data[i],7,index(data[i],"\:")-8)"\n"data[i+4];print i";"data[i] > ("Lamme_register.txt")}' file
```

Comment: Please explain how this is supposed to work, because it itsn't working correctly. It prints vs editing in-place, and I cannot fully determine which variable refers to what parts, the output contains several repeated parts over a lot of lines