# How to replace between some pattern from a source file to target file including those patterns from source file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

### Suppose source_library.txt is the source file and target_file.txt is the target file and I am showing the file contents below using cat command.

```
`$cat source_library.txt
// START method library function
{
common code starts...
I am the library which can be used in target files.
you can use me..
}
// END method library function

$ cat target_file.txt   (before executing that sed command)
My name is Bikram
// START method library function
{
common code starts...

}
// END method library function
Outside of this method.`
```

### Output after executing the below command:

`sed -i '/START method library function/,/END method library function/!b;//!d;/START method library function/r source_library.txt' target_file.txt`

### Output of this command:

```
    `$cat target_file.txt (after executing that sed command)
    My name is Bikram
    // START method library function
    // START method library function
    {
common code starts...
    I am the library which can be used in target files.
    you can use me..
    }
    // END method library function
    // END method library function
    Outside of this method.`
```

### But expected Output I need in target_file.txt as

```
   `My name is Bikram
    // START method library function
    {
    common code starts...
    I am the library which can be used in target files.
    you can use me..
    }
    // END method library function
    Outside of this method.
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` command should do the job:

```
sed -n -i.backup '
    /START method library function/,/END method library function/!p
    /START method library function/r source_library.txt
    /END method library function/{x;p;}
' target_file.txt
```

Note that this `sed` command won't work properly if there is a line containing `START method library function` without a corresponding `END method library function` line.

Comment: Thank you. This command works for me. But only a small issue I faced.
In source_library.txt I need to make an empty line below at the end to work.
Without that it's causing issue in target_file.txt. Mean it's removing one line from end line at every run.

Comment: @BikramBitu The line that I've added to the `sed` expression should do the trick if I understand your request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) is available/acceptable.

The script `script.ed`, name it whatever you like.

```
/START method library function/;/END method library function/;?common code starts...?;/}/-w tmp.txt
E target_file.txt
/{/;/common code/;/}/;?{?r tmp.txt
+;/^$/d
,p
Q
```

---

Now run

```
ed -s source_library.txt < script.ed
```

---

Using a `here document`, something like.

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s source_library.txt <<-'EOF'
  /START method library function/;/END method library function/;?common code starts...?;/}/-w tmp.txt
  E target_file.txt
  /{/;/common code/;/}/;?{?r tmp.txt
  +;/}/-d
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- It creates a temp file (file named `tmp.txt`) which contents are from `source_library.txt`
- Add `!rm tmp.txt` after the line `+;/}/-d` if you don't need the temp file afterwards.
- Remove the `,p` if the output is to `stdout` is not needed.
- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing of target_file.txt is desired.

Answer (score 0):

`cat source_library.txt | sed '/START method library function/,/END method library function/{d;r /dev/stdin}' target_file.txt`

As we discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850429/how-to-write-a-sed-script-that-replaces-the-text-enclosed-between-two-markers/72858701#comment128689114_72858701) you can use the `r /dev/stdin` to ensure that the `r` is reading an empty stream after the first line of the replacement section.